# How to change text color and back ground color of Label with databese info In listview?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my page I use a Listview, which is contains Label;

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    ........
                    ........
                    ........
                        <Label  Text="{Binding .}"
                                TextColor="{DynamicResource Key=textColor}"
                                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                Grid.Row="1">
                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Label>
                    ........
                    ........
                    ........
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I can Change text of Label color with "TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" metod, which i want;

```
        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        var entity = ((Label)sender);

        entity.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("54C642");
        entity.TextColor = Color.FromHex("FFFFFF"); ;
        ...
        ...
        ...                      
    }
```

And i save color informations to sqlite database.

Example Data:
ID:01 ||
Colors:1/54C642,2/EA4B3E,3/54C642,4/D8E330.... (As many as the list view item count)

When page is open, i want to Labels color apply with databese info.
(I can change the Listview items colors and save them to the database of the color information. My main problem is; when opening page load the list with the color information (As in the picture))

[IMAGE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1op5uJGjIusyefDHT6KVPUT9clmDXaCCY/view?usp=sharing)

How can i do?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is the problem image: [IMAGE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nuX7DYAzQ4xtclklrjqvcmdXbfl69UGu/view)

For Label text my data like this ",item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8", for backgroundcolor is ",726E6E,EA4B3E,D8E330,54C642,726E6E,726E6E,726E6E,D8E330".

And so i used two list for itemsource.

**XAML**

```
                                <Label Text="{Binding .}"
                                   BackgroundColor="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource colorconverter}}"
                                   TextColor="{DynamicResource Key=textColor}"
                                   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                   Grid.Row="1">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>
```

**CS**

```
        private async void LstFill()
    {
        App.Current.Resources["textColor"] = Color.FromHex("FFFFFF");

        lstNks.Clear();
        lstColors.Clear();
        string strNks = "";
        string strColors = "";

        _sqLiteConnection = await DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
        var listData = _sqLiteConnection.Table<TBL>().ToList();
        strNoksanlar = listData[index].T1NKS;
        strRenkler = listData[index].COLOR;

        char[] chr = { ',' };


        if (strNoksanlar != "")
        {
            string[] pNks = strNks.Split(chr);
            string[] pColors = strColors.Split(chr);

            for (int i = 0; i < pNks.Length; i++)
            {
                if (pNks[i] != "")
                {
                    lstNks.Add(i + ". " + pNks[i]);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < pColors.Length; i++)
            {
                if (pColors[i] != "")
                {
                    lstColors.Add(pColors[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        lst1Teftis.ItemsSource = null;
        lst1Teftis.ItemsSource = lstNks;
        lst1Teftis.ItemsSource = lstColors;
    }
```

Comment: This goal can be divided into two steps: 1) [ListView Data Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding) - Have a public property `ObservableCollection<SomeClass> myItems`, where `SomeClass` is one item (that gets displayed in one row of ListView). Add to `SomeClass` a public property `LabelColor`. Then you can do `<Label ... TextColor={Binding LabelColor} ...` 2) Either getter of `LabelColor` needs to get data from sqlite, OR add code to set all LabelColors of myItems in page's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> And i save color informations to sqlite database.Example Data: ID:01
> || Colors:1/54C642,2/EA4B3E,3/54C642,4/D8E330.... (As many as the list
> view item count). When page is open, i want to Labels color apply with
> databese info.

According to your description, you want to save ListView's Label TextColor in database, I suggest you can create new class that contains two or more string to save ListView's items TextColor, then using DataBinding to display.

I create simple sample using sqlite database that you can take a look.

There are two string properties, one is Label text, another is TextColor.

```
public class colorclass
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }       
}
```

Want to bind color property to Label's TextColor, need to use [Xamarin.Forms Binding Value Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters), to convert string to Xamarin.Forms.Color.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <converter:converter1 x:Key="colorconverter" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>

        <ListView x:Name="listview1">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label
                                BackgroundColor="Red"
                                Text="{Binding name}"
                                TextColor="{Binding color, Converter={StaticResource colorconverter}}"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btninsert"
            Clicked="btninsert_Clicked"
            Text=" insert data" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>

public class converter1 : IValueConverter
{
    Color c;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       
       if(value!=null)
        {
          c =Color.FromHex((string)value);
        }
        return c;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Getting ListView current item by `(Label)sender).BindingContext`

```
  private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var entity = ((Label)sender);
        colorclass currentitem = (colorclass)((Label)sender).BindingContext;
        currentitem.color = "54C642";
        conn.Update(currentitem);
      
    }
```

**Update:**

Save listview item color in database, then refresh listview data on contentpage's OnAppearing.

```
 public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
{
    public SQLiteConnection conn;
   
    public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conn = GetSQLiteConnection();
       // conn.CreateTable<colorclass>();
    }
    public SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection()
    {
        var fileName = "colors.db";
        var documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);

        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);

        return connection;
    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var entity = ((Label)sender);
        colorclass currentitem = (colorclass)((Label)sender).BindingContext;
        currentitem.color = "54C642";
        conn.Update(currentitem);
      
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        listview1.ItemsSource = conn.Table<colorclass>().ToList();
    }

  
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply.

Actually, I can change the Listview items colors and save them to the database of the color information.

My main problem is; when opening page load the list with the color information  (As in the picture)

Comment: @HakanDOĞAN Yes, you change listview items color and save then into database, then you can get these info from database on ContentPage's OnAppearing, to load data into listview, please see my update.

Comment: thanks for your help. But i couldn't... I add my all codes about color.

Comment: @HakanDOĞAN Maybe you can try my code firstly, and you can modify some code according to your goal.

Comment: @cherry-bu-msft   I tryed your codes but i have some problems. Can you look my update?

Comment: @HakanDOĞAN No, you can not use two list to bind ListView, just [one list of data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding), so we need to create one model class to contains color and other info.